# How do I automatically activate the browser's vertical scrolling when a popup is too large for the screen?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, flex4.5, mxml, flex-spark

I have a flash application that utilizes a lot of popup title windows that do not have parent containers. I'm having a problem when users with smaller resolutions try to use my application because the popup utility windows will often be too large.

Note that I do not want to re-size the window as that would eliminate a lot of it's clarity and separation of menu bars and tool icons. I just want my application to detect if the window has a height or width property greater than that of the browser's view frame and then activate the respective scroll bar should it be needed.

Any thoughts on how I can do this are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In your embed code you need to change height="100%" to the size of the SWF you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually caved and decided that it was bad design to try and force my application to use the browser's scrolling. Now if the pop-up is too large it resizes to fit and forces scrolling on the TitleWindow or component instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use a slightly different approach.  In the `creationComplete` for your popup class, set the panel's height based on the screen's height (`Capabilities.screenResolutionY`).  This will cause the built-in scrollbars on your panel to be triggered when needed.  If you're currently using a built-in popup utlity (e.g. `Alert`), you'll need to create a custom popup class of your own.